# Using motherboard HDMI connection for separate graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi

I have a [Z97-motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z97A/specifications/) which has an HDMI-connection, along with a [MSI 770 graphics card](http://www.msi.com/product/vga/N770_TF_2GD5OC.html#hero-overview), which sadly only has one HDMI-connection.

I would like to connect my second monitor through HDMI to my graphics card, would that be possible utilizing the motherboard's connection?

*I'm aware HDMI->DVI and similar exists, this is mainly a curious question.*

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s not possible. It will be connected to your CPU-integrated GPU and nowhere else. This is hard-wired and cannot be changed at all.